# I am unable to get checkout as guest in checkout page

Tags: checkout

When I click proceed to checkout on cart page and redirect to checkout page it only shows 
"Login
Already registered?", I also want checkout as guest there but I am unable to show it. Please help me how can I show checkout as guest functionality on checkout page.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can enable guest checkout from `system > configuration > sales > checkout`

Comment: I had already done with it but its not working give me another solution....

Comment: check if you have this in all configuration scopes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what Magento version you are using. 
Anyway this is a configuration setting in the admin panel. 
Go to `System > Configuration > SALES > Checkout > Checkout options`
See the image below 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading CE 1.7->1.9; guest checkout was not showing on the checkout page, only the 'Register' and 'Login' options.

To resolve this, I set the 'Allow Guest Checkout' option to 'No' and saved the config like this. Then switched it back to 'Yes' and saved it again. Perhaps some database fields needed a refresh after the upgrade.